# Go http server handle POST data difference?

Tags: http, go

I have a simple upload form as

```
<html>
<title>Go upload</title>
<body>
<form action="http://localhost:8899/up" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">File Path:</label>
<input type="text" name="filepath" id="filepath">
<p>
<label for="file">Content:</label>
<textarea name="jscontent" id="jscontent" style="width:500px;height:100px" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
<p>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

And server side

```
package main 
import (
    "net/http"
    "log"
)
func defaultHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println(r.PostFormValue("filepath"))
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/up", defaultHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8899", nil)
}
```

The problem is when I use `enctype="multipart/form-data"`, I cannot get the value from client with `r.PostFormValue`, but it's ok if I set to `enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`, go document say

> PostFormValue returns the first value for the named component of the POST
>   or PUT request body. URL query parameters are ignored.
>   PostFormValue calls ParseMultipartForm and ParseForm if necessary and ignores
>   any errors returned by these functions.

So why they did not say anything about `enctype` here ?

Answer (score 1):

If you use `"multiplart/form-data"` form-data encoding type you have to read form values with the [`Request.FormValue()`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue) function (note that not `PostFormValue`!).

Change your `defaultHandler()` function to:

```
func defaultHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println(r.FormValue("filepath"))
}
```

And it will work. The reason for this is because both `Request.FormValue()` and `Request.PostFormValue()` first call `Request.ParseMultipartForm()` if needed (if form encodying type is `multipart` and it has not yet been parsed) and `Request.ParseMultipartForm()` only stores the parsed form name-value pairs in the `Request.Form` and not in `Request.PostForm`: [`Request.ParseMultipartForm() source code`](http://golang.org/src/net/http/request.go?s=24522:24581#L810)

This may well be a bug, but even if this is the intended working, it should be mentioned in the documentation.

Comment: @secmask Then maybe you haven't reloaded the HTML page in your browser or you haven't restarted your application. This works for me.

Comment: I have tried do that both :( , I test, go 1.3.3 and 1.4.1

Comment: @secmask And also change `r.PostFormValue()` to `r.FormValue()`.

Comment: `FormValue` is ok, but why not `PostFormValue` ? , from their document, I think the only different is `PostFormValue` does not use value in query url

Comment: @secmask Edited my answer to explain what you experience based on the implementation (source code) of the `http` package.

Comment: That's right, I think it's seem unclear in implementation/document of `PostFormValue`  here.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to upload files you need to use the `multipart/form-data`enctype, the input field must be `type=file` and use the `FormFile` instead of `PostFormValue` (that returns just a String) method.

```
<html>
<title>Go upload</title>
<body>
    <form action="http://localhost:8899/up" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <label for="filepath">File Path:</label>
        <input type="file" name="filepath" id="filepath">
        <p>
        <label for="jscontent">Content:</label>
        <textarea name="jscontent" id="jscontent" style="width:500px;height:100px" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
        <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func defaultHandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    file, header, err := r.FormFile("filepath")

    defer file.Close()

    if err != nil {
        log.Println(err.Error())
    }

    log.Println(header.Filename)

    // Copy file to a folder or something
}
func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/up", defaultHandler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8899", nil)
}
```

Comment: My form does not have file, just some form param, but I prefer multipart to url encoding form. It"s just weird go did not do it uniform here(and document)